# How can I use launchmyapp with Meteor for the verify-email link?

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins, custom-url

I'm using the Meteoric package to run ionic on my meteor app. I'd like to use the https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme (nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp plugin) in my app. Actually I am using it, but it isn't working right.

I'm trying to use this plugin to deep link from a URL into my app. Right now I'm just trying to get it to work with the verify-email link. I click the link and it takes me into the app, but it always wants me to login first.

The link that is being sent looks like this.

```
myappname://verify-email/longtokenidhere1212332
```

If I click this my app does launch, but it always ask for the user login credentials instead of verifying the email address.

Update 1:

I have this almost working. I added handleOpenURL as a global function like below

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    handleOpenURL = function handleOpenURL(url) {
        var token = url.replace("myappname://verify-email/", "");
        console.log("Token: " + token);
        Router.go('/verify-email/', {"paramToken": token});
    }
});
```

Now I do see the token print to the console.

But when it routes I get a route not found page. How can I print the current URL from the console to see if I'm getting to the right full URL path? I tried window.URL, but that prints the URLConstructor() object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"/verify-email" is not an iron router route; it's baked into meteor itself.

So instead of Router.go(), you can make a call to [Accounts.verifyEmail](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_verifyemail) from the client, like this:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
    handleOpenURL = function handleOpenURL(url) {
        var token = url.replace("myappname://verify-email/", "");
        console.log("Token: " + token);
        // mark this client's email as verified by using the token
        Accounts.verifyEmail(token, 
            function(error){
               if (error) {
                   console.log("email not verified");
               } else {
                   console.log("email verified successfully!");
               }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it for sure.